# Sql Server Error 26 Local

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

(The database is on my PC)

My database worked just fine for a month, and then this error came. It is not related to a specific file, nor a specific project (Even if I'll create a new website and try to add a new database file, this error will pop)

I guess it happens because the sql server is not running on my PC, and it is true that I don't see any sql related process running.

How the I fix it?

P.S. I know this error has a lot of threads on the internet and even here in SO. But most of them solve the problem for a complicated, secured connection with a remote server. All I want is to create a new empty ASP.NET website and add a new .mdf file for it on my PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be related with the SQL Service authentication which you have to verify from the control panel->Administrative tools->Services. Locate SQL Server(Express) Try changing the Log on As Network Service instead of local system.

Comment: I have no idea what these options mean, but it is already set as "Network Service". However, I knew what my problem was (The sql server is not running) and by showing me this services list I was able to start the sql server service, it now runs and I can see it in the processes (sqlservr.exe) and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

that is a error Locating Server or Instance.

Try connecting by IP.

Have you disabled SQL Server browser?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing something similar so I will share how I solved it, it might work for you or not, but here are my 2 cents.

**My environment:** Windows 10 ( upgraded from windows 8 in which SQL Server was working fine) 
SQL Server 2014 Express

**Solution:** I Opened the services program, and found the SQL Server services, I saw that all of of them were up except by one which was disabled, the "**SQL Server Agent**", I enabled it and was able to connect to my DB instance.

Hope it helps

Regards